# What is the function definition to be able to pass an assignment as a parameter

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm in the process of refactoring some code old. Now one of the issues I'm facing is

```
 AllFields.Add(SomeProperty = new IntField
            {
                ColumnName = "SomeProperty",
                DisplayName = "Some Property",
                IsEditable = false,
                IsRequired = true
            });
```

Now what I want is something along the lines of perhaps an extension method which takes the assignment of 
`SomeProperty = new IntField()` as a parameter

e..g

```
public static class Extensions  
{  
  public static void Add(this IList<IField> source, SomeParameter value)  
  {  
  }  
}
```

so that I can do

```
IList<IField> AllFields = new List<IField>();  
AllFields.Add(SomeProperty = new IntField(){});
AllFields.Add(SomeProperty2 = new DecimalField(){});
```

I forgot to add . SomeProperty and SomeProperty is of type int and decimal

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of generics for this. Something like the following would be sufficient:

```
public static class Extensions  
{  
    public static void Add<T>(this IList<T> source, SomeParameter value) 
        where T : IField, new()  
    {  
    }  
}
```

Essentialy, you define a generic method whose only generic parameter `T` should have a parameterless constructor (`where T : new()`) and implements the interface `IField`.

Doing so, you could write something like the following one:

```
IList<IField> AllFields = new List<IField>();  
AllFields.Add(new IntField(){});
AllFields.Add(new DecimalField(){});
```

You could also have something like the below:

```
IField SomeProperty;
IField SomeProperty2;

IList<IField> AllFields = new List<IField>();  
AllFields.Add(SomeProperty = new IntField(){});
AllFields.Add(SomeProperty2 = new DecimalField(){});
```

However I don't see any usage of this from that you have described you want to do.

Comment: OK., Well allow me to explain why. Previously SomeProperty was of type IntField, DecimalField which implements IField... Now Im trying to get rid of all this IField nonsense but its still required in some places.

Comment: Perhaps if I firstly implement some form of implicit converter to allow things such as "int = IntField"  .. hmm...

Comment: @Eminem I don't get your point. Since you have written that you want to create a `List<IField>` how can you at the same time you want to get rid off the interface `IField`?